# What does the OS do when you run java bytecode? How it interact with the JVM?

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm

I have been studying Operating systems in my free time, but I am confused about how it works with Java & the JVM.

Some questions
when running the java bytecode using a command like `java file.class`:

1. I understand that JVM optimize and interpret or perform JIT of the program
2. How does the JVM get CPU allocation for doing these in a multi-threaded application?

My assumption: In each thread of this application, they all use the same per-process JVM to perform these tasks. (Is this correct?)

What is the role of the operating system with the JVM, what interaction do they have?

Comment: A lot of this is implementation-defined. A compliant JVM can literally be a chip that *in silico* executes Java bytecode directly on a hardware stack. If I had a large enough whiteboard, a whiteboard marker, and enough time on my hands, I myself could be a compliant JVM.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov your whiteboard doesn’t need to be extraordinarily large, as you are allowed to signal insufficient resources with a dedicated `Error` at any time.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Image showing stack of User layer accessing Application layer built on top of Operating System layer built on top of Hardware layer.]

([image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Operating_system_placement.svg))

## JVM is just an app

The [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) as seen in the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project is just another app, usually written in [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) and [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), sometimes [written in Java](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/01/graalvm-21-jvm-java/).

From the point of view of the host operating system, running a JVM is just like running a word-processor, a spreadsheet, or a web browser. All of these apps are large, consuming much memory and spawning threads.

As someone commented, a JVM technically is any software and/or hardware that complies with the [official specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Indeed, there have been attempts at building hardware chips that knew how to execute Java butecode (see [*Jazelle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor)) but they did not succeed afaik. In practice today, the JVMs we download from [Oracle](http://java.sun.com) or [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net) or [other distributors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMesK.jpg) are **simply C/C++ apps that run like any other app** on your Mac, BSD, Linux, Windows, AIX, Solaris, or similar machine.

> I understand that JVM optimize and interpret or perform JIT of the program

[HyperCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperCard) from Apple is vintage software similar to Java in that it too executed code internally through an interpreter with a JIT so that repeated runs of the same code blocks would suddenly run faster. HyperCard too was just another app from the point of view of the Mac operating system.

> How does the JVM get CPU allocation for doing these in a multi-threaded application?

By [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) on [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) like any other [app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software). Word-processors use threads for writing to storage in the background and for re-rendering the document on the background. Web browsers might allocate threads for handling each web page in separate windows/tabs.

> In each thread of this application, they all use the same per-process JVM to perform these tasks. (Is this correct?)

Yes, with OpenJDK, you will see one [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) on your [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) for the JVM. All the threads of all the Java apps running within that JVM are housed within that single OS process. However, as someone commented, these are mere [implementation details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation#Computer_science). People are free to implement a JVM as they see fit, in any manner they choose, as long as they comply with the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

## See the source code

[*OpenJDK*](https://openjdk.java.net) is open-source. So if you are really curious, [peruse that source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk). Note that you will find areas of code specific to each OS, such as [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS) versus [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) versus [MS Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), on each CPU type, such as [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) or [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) or [SPARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC) or such, where the JVM interacts with the host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).